# GFCI outlet with two branches

Tags: wiring

I am adding a wet bar to my already finished basement. I am going to replace a regular outlet that is under the counter with a GFCI outlet (to meet code). The outlet is in the middle of the run (on a 15A circuit).

I want to add an outlet above the new GFCI outlet and I'm curious if I can pigtail off of the load side of the GFCI so that the new outlet above it and the other outlets downstream will be protected.

Comment: Since you list a 15 amp and GFCI receptacle,  I answered for North America power. I believe Canada limits the number of receptacles like the NEC does for commercial and industrial, but the NEC has no limit for residential (so far).

Answer (score 7):

Absolutely yes ! you could have as many receptacles fed off this load terminal as you want! (Pig-tailing is the right way to do multiples)

Would you like 1,2,3 branch circuits going in different directions from the load? This is 100% code compliant!

Caution there are internet only electricians that do not understand both code and the use of the load terminals your use of the load for multiple loads , branches is code and device compliant.

Comment: Okay thank you so much -- I appreciate your help!

Comment: If a answer is helpful we get our thanks from upvotes the up arrow or check marks for accepted answers. The check helps others find an accepted answer when they may have the same question.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you (will) have 2 branches coming off the GFCI receptacle.  That is fine.

For each branch, decide whether it makes sense for that branch to be GFCI-protected **and** you want their ground faults to trip **this** GFCI device... and if "yes", then that branch's hot and neutral go on the "Load" terminals.

Otherwise they go on the "Line" terminals.  If you want the GFCI protection but don't want the mutual trip, those branches can be protected by their own GFCI outlets further down the line.  *This might be relevant to a thing like a refrigerator, where you want the least probability of a nuisance trip*.

Also, sticking "GFCI Protected" labels on all downline receptacles is mandatory per Code.*  If you hate those stickers, either make your own (which is fine) or don't use "Load" and protect them with their own GFCI receps if need be.

---

* A vast web of Codes, including NEC (110.3B) and UL's practices in approving the instructions of GFCI receptacles. It's not *just* in every brand of GFCI's instructions, it's specifically 8(c) in every brand's instructions.

Comment: Harper the sticker is only required if there is no equipment ground. GFCI breakers don’t come with stickers so having GFCI protected on almost every receptacle in a kitchen, bathroom, garage, basement,,, you get the idea I haven’t been flagged on it for the last 3 homes we wired. I guess you could say if the mfg instructions say to do it but go into a new build you don’t see stickers on everything and they just went through inspection.

Comment: Note I just double checked both code and a receptacle install sheet ( Leviton GFWR2) The sheet had no instructions either.  Only if no equipment ground is the sticker required!  unless you can provide a code reference.  No equipment ground 406.4.3. Exception, no sticker is required. Please quit coming up with internet only electricians comments! There is no requirement for the stickers on a circuit with an equipment ground.

Comment: The flip side is that the day my kitchen was finished, *with no stickers then or now*, I had a brand new receptacle go dead. I called my electrician - he was still on his way home. He was about to turn around and then said "Check all the GFCIs!" I did, problem solved. If I had stickers, I would have known... But now I know - anything in kitchen or bathroom (which he took care of a few years later) goes dead, check the GFCIs (all over the kitchen, other bathrooms).

Comment: @EdBeal ***Wrong***.  Read the instructions closer.  Hint: 8(C).  Hint: *How did Harper know it would be 8(C) without even knowing what manufacturer's GFCI?*  Oh wait, I see where you do mention the model - full points for showing your work - but it's 8(C) on every GFCI instructions.  That "Internet electrician" rant of yours is going to get you in big trouble one day.  [0:11 in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z3Viv88ZOFA).

Comment: I use the little stickers bc it's not always obvious the outlet is GFCI protected, esp. if from a different room.

Comment: I did mis that after reading it but as I said you will not find any stickers in most houses as the breakers don’t come with them. But sorry to pop your bubble.  I am what most states consider a master electrician. The difference most states master electricians have to have plans signed off by an engineer , my license is higher than that as I am a signing supervisor the guy that doesn’t need an engineer . On top of that with scuba I am a retired instructor trainer , the guy that trains instructors that then they train the master divers and dive masters I mastered that 30 years ago still diving

Comment: @EdBeal Diving sounds like a blast, and agreed - no place for amateurs.   But you know how it works. Lots of master electricians don't re-mark white wires or use torque screwdrivers.  And lots of inspectors let 'em do it. (heck, just *mentioning* torque screwdrivers is "fighting words" on most electrician forums).   I don't feel right giving "what you can get away with" advice because *the day you do* is the day the OP will get pinched by an inspector who's a stickler... or who's trying to prove an amateur wrong (you wouldn't know any pros like that, would you? ;)

Comment: By the way, the invisible hand making it 8(C) on every brand's instructions is UL.  Another subtle way that the electrical codes work, which might not be apparent to a "master of one".